# How do i completely remove otrs and fix my previous localhost

Tags: apache2, localhost, otrs

I followed a guide on [how to install and configure otrs](http://ownlinuxnotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/install-and-configure-otrs-in-ubuntu/), it didn't work. Now When I tip in Firefox `localhost` it cannot connect to it.

I tried to remove everything, but still no luck.

I removed everything in the folder `/opt/otrs*`

I put a `#` in front of  `Include sites-enabled/`

and restarting apache but  get a

> .....Action 'start' failed...

**Question**: *How do i completely remove otrs*(and fix my localhost!)

Comment: I completely removed apache and dependencies and reinstalled it. and after a restart it was working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Removing faulty otrs**

```
 sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/otrs.conf
 sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/otrs.conf
 sudo rm /home/$USER/.cache/software-center/piston-helper/rec.ubuntu.com,api,1.0,recommend_app,otrs,,81384ef50f6b1038436de465afd51202
 sudo rm /home/$USER/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,nl,any,any,any,otrs,page,1,helpful,,251358f9bbc99053ed71c6082e485827

 sudo rm /home/$USER/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,nl,ubuntu,quantal,any,otrs,page,1,helpful,,7af23859b6e91926d3623a0d118dbf90

 sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/otrs2_3.1.7+dfsg1-5_all.deb 
 sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/otrs_3.1.7+dfsg1-5_all.deb 
 sudo rm /var/crash/otrs2.0.crash 
 sudo rm /var/crash/otrs2.0.upload 
 sudo rm /var/crash/otrs2.0.uploaded
```

just in case I missed something:

```
 sudo apt-get -y autoremove
 sudo apt-get -y clean
 sudo apt-get -y autoclean
 sudo apt-get -y check
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

**Source**:

- [How to install the latest otrs - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-otrs#remov-code)
- [Bug #1154530 “package otrs2 3.1.7+dfsg1-5 failed to install/upgr...” : Bugs : “otrs2” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/otrs2/+bug/1154530)

Answer (score 0):

I read you already fixed it. If you set up OTRS as in the tutorial the 'proper' way would have been:

```
a2dissite otrs
rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/otrs.conf
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```